# How do I make a messy sculpted surface smooth?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, mirror, smooth

I have recently gotten into using the sculpting tab in Blender. I have always just used the layout tab, manually moving vertices, using modifiers, creating faces and edges, etc... But I have started getting into building more complex shapes and I think the sculpting tab is starting to become necessary.

I tried making a boat and I figured that I needed the sculpting tab to make the sloping rounded hull of the boat. This is me sculpting the hull of the boat:
[image]

To make it match, I deleted one side of the boat.
[image]

I used the mirror modifier to get the two sides to match
[image]

The issue is that you can't even out the messy surface after sculpting.
[image]

The surface is lumpy, and I need it perfectly smooth the way that boat hulls look. So is there something I can do to make the surface flush? Maybe take an average of the surface geometry and make a perfect curve?

Comment: Hey Christian, have you tried to work with a SubD-Modelling workflow? 
This would remove the problem of bumpiness in your mesh. 

If you want to still use the Sculpt i'd Recommend you to use the smooth brush on a low Strenght setting and adding a SubD Modifier on it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm looking into SubD-Modelling workflow now

Comment: If you want i can post a solution for you with sub d Modelling workflow. Im not sure if it would be a valid Answer for you Question though (Stackoverflow Rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you a SubD Workflow for smooth Geometry.

I'm going to show you in this example how you can model your ship.

- Add a simple plane
- Scale it along the Y or X axis until you have your full length
- Apply the scale (Ctrl + A "Apply Scale")
- Loop cut edges (Ctrl + S "Scroll to add more edges")
- Repeat on other axis

[image]

- Scale the most outer edges inward along your axis

[image]

- Add a SubD modifier
- In Edit mode, move the most inner Face along the Z-Axis down

[image]

- To sharpen the Edges again, select them in Edit mode and change the crease setting

[image]

- After that, it's up to you how you add the details (cutouts).
- You can use the knife tool and increase the crease on each cutout again
  or Apply the SubD and remove Faces where necessary.